# Terraform - host for provisioner cannot be empty

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, devops

I am using Terraform to provision an EC2 instance on AWS. The Terraform file is able to provision the EC2-instance, however, when it gets to the provisioner section of the script, I get the error "host for provisioner cannot be empty" despite the host value being labelled.

instance.tf file

```
resource "aws_key_pair" "dove-key" {
  key_name   = "dovekey"
  public_key = file("dovekey.pub")
}

resource "aws_instance" "dove-inst" {
  ami                    = var.AMIS[var.REGION]
  instance_type          = "t2.micro"
  availability_zone      = var.ZONE1
  key_name               = aws_key_pair.dove-key.key_name
  subnet_id              = "subnet-00a20e364a10aed04"
  vpc_security_group_ids = ["sg-0ddc62a99b3e5d75d"]

  tags = {
    Name    = "Dove-Instance"
    Project = "Dove"
  }

  provisioner "file" {
    source      = "web.sh"
    destination = "/tmp/web.sh"

    connection {
      type        = "ssh"
      user        = var.USER
      password    = ""
      private_key = file("dovekey")
      host        = self.public_ip
    }
  }

  provisioner "remote-exec" {
    inline = [
      "chmod u+x /tmp/web.sh",
      "sudo /tmp/web.sh"
    ]

    connection {
      type        = "ssh"
      user        = var.USER
      password    = ""
      private_key = file("dovekey")
      host        = self.public_ip
    }
  }
}
```

vars.tf file

```
variable "REGION" {
  default = "us-west-1"
}

variable "ZONE1" {
  default = "us-west-1b"
}

variable "AMIS" {
  type = map(any)
  default = {
    us-west-1 = "ami-09ab9d570789dfdd4"
    us-east-1 = "ami-0e8a34246278c21e4"
  }
}

variable "USER" {
  default = "ec2-user"

}
```

I expected the script to ran completely without error

Comment: Did my answer work for you?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the issue is that the EC2 instance being launched is not allocated a public IP address (most likely due to subnet settings) therefore `self.public_ip` does not evaluate to a valid address, and thus terraform errors out.

Fix your subnet so that the instance is given a public ip address.

Comment: Hi Paolo, this was exactly it! The subnet was not set to automatically allocate IP addresses to the instances.

Answer (score 1):

You're going to have tons of problems using a remote provisioner like this. Provisioners in Terraform are a "last resort" that you should only use if nothing else works. It is much more reliable to place those two commands in an [EC2 User Data](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html) script.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add on to Paolo's point, the `aws_instance` resource allows you to output the `public_ip` ([source](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/instance#public_ip)) attribute which'll tell you the public IP it currently has (if it does infact have one). Example here:

```
 output "public_ip" {
   description = "Public IP of dove-inst instance"
   value       = aws_instance.dove-inst.public_ip
 }
```

What Mark's said is definitely valid. It's not what you've asked, but I'd consider looking at if the contents of `web.sh` can be executed in another way. For example, is it something you may want to build into an Amazon Machine Image (AMI)?

EDIT: One thing to add, you've not specified a startup script. Do you think you could execute the contents of `web.sh` using that instead?